# boost::beast "stream truncated" error when parsing http stream chunks

Tags: c++, boost, https, boost-beast, http-streaming

I use `boost::beast` to get data over HTTPS stream. (in particular from [EXANTE API](https://api-live.exante.eu/api-docs/#tag/Orders-stream-API) ).
My code is almost identical to the example from the official documentation of the Beast library: [Chunked encoding](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/using_http/chunked_encoding.html).

Everything works correctly, but periodically reading chunks is interrupted by `"Stream truncated"` or `"Partial message"` errors. I can't understand the cause of these errors. Is it in my code, or is it a problem with the internet connection or the server, or maybe the connection is interrupted by a proxy server or firewall (idk).

**UPD:** Traffic analysis via Wireshark showed that before the error occurs, I receive a TLS message `"Encrypted alert (21)"`. But I don't understand what it can mean and how it can be interpreted.

A maximally simplified version of my code is shown below.
P.S. The data is from a test account, so it is not secret.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/archive/iterators/base64_from_binary.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/iterators/transform_width.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

#include <boost/asio/connect.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl/stream.hpp>

#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/http.hpp>

using namespace std::string_literals;
namespace net   = boost::asio;
namespace ssl   = boost::asio::ssl;
namespace ip    = boost::asio::ip;
namespace beast = boost::beast;
namespace http  = boost::beast::http;
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;

std::string base64_encode(const std::string& val) {
    using namespace boost::archive::iterators;
    using It = base64_from_binary<transform_width<std::string::const_iterator, 6, 8>>;
    auto tmp = std::string(It(std::begin(val)), It(std::end(val)));
    return tmp.append((3 - val.size() % 3) % 3, '=');
}

int main() {

    const auto clientID = "6dc42e50-0b01-444e-bae0-3a431c88b525"s;
    const auto key = "TTQmWnbHlr5OWlNSWl1P"s;
    const auto host = "api-demo.exante.eu"s;
    const auto target = "/trade/3.0/stream/orders"s;
    const auto port = "443"s;
    const auto http_version = 11;
    const auto auth_token = "Basic "s + base64_encode(clientID + ':' + key);
    const auto accept_value = "application/x-json-stream"s;
    const auto timeout = std::chrono::seconds(12);

    http::request<http::string_body> request{http::verb::get, target, http_version};
    request.set(http::field::host, host);
    request.set(http::field::user_agent, BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING);
    request.set(http::field::authorization, auth_token);
    request.set(http::field::accept, accept_value);
    request.prepare_payload();

    net::io_context ioc;

    ssl::context ctx(ssl::context::tlsv12_client);
    tcp::resolver resolver(ioc);
    beast::ssl_stream<beast::tcp_stream> stream(ioc, ctx);
    if (!SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(stream.native_handle(), host.c_str())) {
        beast::error_code ec{static_cast<int>(::ERR_get_error()), net::error::get_ssl_category()};
        throw beast::system_error{ec};
    }
    auto const results = resolver.resolve(host, port);

    beast::get_lowest_layer(stream).connect(results);
    stream.handshake(ssl::stream_base::client);

    http::write(stream, request);

    beast::flat_buffer buffer;
    http::parser<false, http::empty_body> p;

    http::read_header(stream, buffer, p);

    http::chunk_extensions ce;
    std::string chunk;

    auto header_cb =
            [&](std::uint64_t size,
                beast::string_view extensions,
                beast::error_code &ev) {
                ce.parse(extensions, ev);
                if (ev)
                    return;

                if (size > (std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max)()) {
                    ev = http::error::body_limit;
                    return;
                }

                chunk.reserve(static_cast<std::size_t>(size));
                chunk.clear();
            };
    p.on_chunk_header(header_cb);

    auto body_cb =
            [&](std::uint64_t remain,
                beast::string_view body,
                beast::error_code &ec) {
                if (remain == body.size())
                    ec = http::error::end_of_chunk;

                chunk.append(body.data(), body.size());

                return body.size();
            };
    p.on_chunk_body(body_cb);

    std::function<void(const beast::error_code &, size_t)> onRead = [&](const auto &ec, auto bytes_transferred) {
        if (ec && ec != http::error::end_of_chunk)
            throw std::runtime_error(ec.what());

        for (auto const &extension: ce) {
            std::cout << "Extension: " << extension.first;
            if (!extension.second.empty())
                std::cout << " = " << extension.second << std::endl;
            else
                std::cout << std::endl;
        }

        static int counter = 0;
        std::cout << "Chunk Body: " << chunk << counter++ << " @@@!" << std::endl;
        chunk.clear();
        if (!p.is_done()) {
            stream.next_layer().expires_after(timeout);
            http::async_read(stream, buffer, p, onRead);
        }
    };

    stream.next_layer().expires_after(timeout);
    http::async_read(stream, buffer, p, onRead);

    ioc.run();
    
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried both synchronous and asynchronous versions of `http::read` functions, the problem occurs in any case.

The error occurs on three different devices on different networks.

According to the API developers, there are no restrictions on the duration of HTTP stream listening.
The problem occurs every time after a random period of time from a couple of minutes to several hours.

Comment: "According to the API developers, there are no restrictions on the duration of HTTP stream listening." - please include a link to the documentation of that. Also, "no restriction" doesn't mean "a guarantee on infinite listening". In fact, no such guarantee can technically exist.

Comment: @sehe Unfortunately this is not stated in the documentation, I had to contact technical support to find out. 
However, it doesn't seem to be a deliberate server-side shutdown, because even when running on 3 devices simultaneously, this error occurs at different times, sometimes differing by several orders of magnitude.

Comment: So? You could have some network flakiness. In fact that's common. If you have frequent disconnects you might find out the cause (e.g. using wireshark or eliminating bottlenecks like switches/routers and proxies)

Comment: @sehe But I don't get such errors when, for example, receiving data via websocket or interacting with the server via rest api. 
So I can't be sure that the problem is in the internet connection, but I can't rule it out either.
I don't really understand what are the ways to check why the stream breaks: because of a program error, internet problems or peculiarities of the server behavior

Comment: Either add debug tracing or using packet dumper (pcap, tcpdump, ethereal, wireshark etc).

Comment: @sehe But it's not like I'll be able to see the contents of messages transmitted over TLS. How can I determine what the error is? 
There is nothing to debug in the program itself: at one iteration of the async_read function callback completed successfully and printed the content of the chunk, and at the next iteration it completed with an error.

Comment: You can tell the state of the connection at the time where you receive the error. I'm not saying it's *easy* to trace. If you have the tools/skills you might interpose a MITM ssl proxy (mitm-proxy, Burp, AFAICT even wireshark has support built-in?). I reckon you should be able to glean all relevant information from within your own code though. The value of dumps is only for post-mortem and "batch" analysis

Comment: @sehe Updated the question. Before the error occurs, I receive the TLS message "Encrypted alert (21)", but I do not understand what this means and how to get more detailed information.

Comment: It's important so see which end is sending the alert, it could well be a regular close-notify (again, very likely it is). To find more information you inspect the logs of the sending side. To actually inspect the packet you could debug into the TLS code, use a debugger with trace capability from the point where you receive the first error code, or indeed use a MITM proxy like I mentioned before.